# HTML textarea shows dynamic text half the height

Tags: html, css, textarea

HTML `<textarea>` shows dynamic text half its height when it first loads [when the page loads] like this:
[image]

When you focus and start typing or pushing left or right arrow keys, then it shows the text to its full height as it should like this.
[image]

How to make the dynamic text appear at its full height when it first loads without having to focus on the `<textarea>` and push right/left arrow keys? Here is the HTML and CSS codes:

```css
textarea {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #009688;
  font-size: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="location" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Its always better to provide jsfiddle so we can try and answer.
Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fbo38wx2/

Comment: @TavishAggarwal it's always better to use a stack snippet rather than a fiddle

Comment: @Pete Yes correct!

Comment: You may check my answer. I have an explanation for it, and will add more if you have some question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the height to include the padding and border size as you have used box-sizing so your height should be the size of the font plus top and bottom padding and border

In this case that is 55px (font) + 24px (12px top and 12px bottom padding) + 2px (border - you have no top and 2px bottom) = 81px

```css
textarea {
    height: 81px;
    background-color: #009688;
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height:55px;         /* added this just to ensure the line height is the same as the font size */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="location" style="overflow:hidden">someText</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and explanation. It worked fine.

Comment: @Din, forgot it should include the border too, see edit

Comment: beautiful. That is super explanation. Thank you Pete very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the padding/margin you have added. Try running by removing the padding/margin and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  I just remove the padding. You can also add the **padding** just add more **height**

**Explanation:**

The size of font and the height of `textarea` is the same **PLUS** you have a padding.

```css
textarea {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #009688;
    font-size: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    /*padding: 12px 20px;*/
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="location" style="overflow:hidden">Prefilled</textarea>
```

Comment: does not work if you have prefilled text. answer is wrong

Comment: What do you mean by prefilled text?

Comment: if you put some text in between `<textarea ... >` and `</textarea>` then click run the text will still be half visible.

Comment: Are you sure?  I added the text inside

Comment: yes, I am, when you run the code and then if you start typing, you will see that the text will jump and move up.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated one. Added line-height and updated attribute to `rows=1` instead of giving height to textarea.

```css
textarea {
    min-height: 55px;
    background-color: #009688;
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="location" rows="1" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase height as height and font-size is same:

```
textarea {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #009688;
    font-size: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust font-size and padding like

```
padding: 12px 12px;
and 
font-size: 40px;
```